# Jquery click funtion is not working when mobile view

Tags: html, jquery, responsive

I have jquery click funtion which is to close custom modal. It's working perfectly except when I'm on mobile view (I use different type of browser but still not working when it's on mobile view)
I wonder why it's not working when mobile view.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cus-close").click(function() {
    $(".custom-modal").css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-modal">
  <div class="content">
    <i class="fa fa-times cus-close"></i>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>Add success</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `.tap` in case of mobile view... keep both `.click` and `.tap` if you want your page to work in both devices

Comment: @AdityaParab jQuery has no `.tap()` method.

Comment: yep.. @RoryMcCrossan, need to add jquery mobile

Comment: Adding an entire library for one method, which can be achieved in another manner without that library, seems rather wasteful.

Comment: `.on('touchend', fn)` could work though...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes when it is on mobile device view

Comment: In that case try `on('click touchend', function() {...` as @AdityaParab suggested

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Still work only on windows device view, still not working on mobile device view.